# Why does Django not allow a user to extract a usable query from a QuerySet as a standard feature?

Tags: python, django

In Django, you can extract a plain-text SQL query from a `QuerySet` object like this:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters)
sql = str(queryset.query)
```

In most cases, this query itself is not valid - you can't pop this into a SQL interface of your choice or pass it to `MyModel.objects.raw()` without exceptions, since quotations (and possibly other features of the query) are not performed by Django but rather by the database interface at execution time. So at best, this is a useful debugging tool.

Coming from a data science background, I often need to write a lot of complex SQL queries to aggregate data into a reporting format. The Django ORM can be awkward at best and impossible at worst when queries need to be very complex. However, it does offer some security and convenience with respect to limiting SQL injection attacks and providing a way to dynamically build a query - for example, generating the WHERE clause for the query using the `.filter()` method of a model. I want to be able to use the ORM to generate a base data set in the form of a query, then take that query and use it as a subquery/CTE in a larger query that handles more complex logic. For example:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters)
sql = str(queryset.query)

more_complex_query = f"""
with filtered_table as ({sql})
select
   *
   /* add other stuff */
from
   filtered_table
"""

results = MyModel.objects.raw(more_complex_query)
```

In this case, the ORM generates a query that can be used to filter the base table, then the CTE/raw sql can take that result and do whatever calculations need to be done with a tool that is more common among people working with data (SQL) than the Django ORM, while still getting the ORM benefits of stripping bad actors out.

However, this method requires a way to generate a usable SQL query from a `QuerySet` object. I've found a workaround for postgres databases using the `psycopg2` cursor:

```
from django.db import connections

# Whatever the key is in your settings.DATABASES for the reporting db
WAREHOUSE_CONNECTION_NAME = 'default'

# Get the Query object and separate it into the query and params
filtered_table_query = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters).query
raw_query, params = filtered_table_query.sql_with_params()

# Create a cursor from the relevant connection
cursor = connections[WAREHOUSE_CONNECTION_NAME].cursor()

# Call .mogrify() on the query/params to get an executable query string
usable_sql = cursor.mogrify(raw_query, params)

cursor.execute(usable_sql)  # This works
cursor.fetchall()  # This works

# Have not tried this yet
MyModel.objects.raw(usable_sql)

# Or this
wrapper_query = f"""
with base_table as ({usable_sql})
select
    *
from
    base_table
"""

cursor.execute(wrapper_query)
# or
MyModel.objects.raw(wrapper_query)
```

This method is dependent on the `psycopg2` cursor method `.mogrify()` - I am not sure if this works for other back ends or if the DB API 2.0 spec takes care of that.

Other people have suggested creating a view in the database and then using an unmanaged Django model on top of the view, but I think this does not really work when your queries are dynamic in nature, i.e. need to be filtered differently based on some user input, since often the fields a user wants to filter on are not present in the result set after some aggregation.

So overall, I have two questions:

1. Is there a reason why Django does not let you extract a usable SQL query as a standard offering?
2. What other methods do people use when the ORM makes your elegant SQL into an ugly mess?

Comment: 1. The quotation and escaping of the SQL query is done by the database adapter. This is a simple and effective way of preventing SQL injections by user supplied values. The adapter knows how to handle that for its own database.

Comment: 2. You might have missed the point that the ORM is an abstraction layer, taking SQL out of your focus.

Comment: @KlausD. 1. yes, I am aware of that (I mentioned it in the post). But Django could still provide a method to retrieve the executable query if the adapter supports that - in my example, the psycopg2 provides the `mogrify` method on the cursor which properly escapes/quotes the input (preventing SQL injection) but provides the SQL query to the user. There are many reasons why a user might want this, my post shows one use-case.

Comment: @KlausD. 2. Yes, it's an abstraction layer, but clearly the authors intended for users to still use raw SQL in some capacity since the `.raw()` methods exist, and similarly the `.extra()` methods on query sets use SQL syntax. Why provide a way to execute raw queries against the database but not allow us to extract the exact query that will be executed from the ORM?

Comment: Considering your comments I see that you are not asking for the technical backgrounds. It seems like you want to debate Django design decisions. Stack Overflow is not the right place for that.

Comment: I am not debating - I am asking a question. Please re-read. Even if you disagree that the first part of my question is not appropriate for SO - the second part remains. What methods are preferred when the ORM alone is insufficient for a given query that needs to be made, and raw SQL must be used in some form? Your response was that the ORM abstracts away SQL from my focus - which is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Django developers tend to frown on features that aren't cross-compatible across all the databases they support.  I can only imagine that one of the supported database engines doesn't have this capability and so they don't provide it as a standard, documented feature of the ORM.

But that's just a guess.  You'd really have to ask one of the devs :)